# How to simplify $2^{\lceil log_2(n) \rceil} - 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, rounding-error

I'm trying to proof: $\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor + 2^{\lceil log_2(n) \rceil} - 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor} ∈ O(log_2(n)) {} {} | n ∈ \mathbb N$

Therefore I need to solve this equaty:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor + 2^{\lceil log_2(n) \rceil} - 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}} {log_2(n)} < \infty$

But I didn't come further than

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor + 2^{\lceil log_2(n) \rceil} - 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}} {log_2(n)} \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{log_2(n) + 2^{\lceil log_2(n) \rceil} - 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}} {log_2(n)} $

Do you know a solution?

Comment: This does not seem right: take $n=1+2^k$.

Comment: @lhf I just realised there is a -1 missing at the end. But that shouldn't make a difference, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log_2(n)$ is integer, i.e. $n=2^k,\,k\in\mathbb Z_+$ then
$$\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil=\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor=k$$
Otherwise
$$\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil=\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor+1\implies 2^{\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil}=2\times2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor}$$
In this case, there is $m$ such that
$$n=2^k+m,\;2^{k-1}\le m<2^k$$
So it comes to this:
$$2^{\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil}-2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor}=
\begin{cases}
0&n=2^k\\2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor}&n=2^k+m
\end{cases}$$
and we can see that in the second case, $2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor}=2^k$ where $2^k<n<2^{k+1}$

Comment: That's briliant! Thank you!

Comment: @oRookie you're welcome ;)